# problemas con ñ al subir archivos al servidor

Tags: php

Tengo problemas con el nombre de los archivos no me guarda la letra 'ñ'
mi codigo:

```
<?php  
$direccion = '../archivos';
$tipo = $_FILES['archivosubirmedios']['type'];
$name = basename($_FILES["archivosubirmedios"]["name"]);
$ruta = "archivos/$name";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivosubirmedios']['tmp_name'],"$direccion/$name")) {
        chmod("$direccion/$name",0600);
        echo "Archivo Guardado ";
        }
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: haz comprobado que funcionen todos los niveles de utf-8?

Comment: ni idea amigo, ¿como es eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta `utf8_decode()`
para obtener el nombre del archivo antes de guardarlo en la base de datos

Saludos

Comment: En la base de datos guarda el nombre bien, el problema es con el nombre del archivo en la carpeta, me lo guarda como "muÃ±eco" en lugar de "muñeco"

Comment: ¿cual es el Sistema operativo que usa tu server?

Comment: Windows 10, ya lo pude corregir con `utf8_decode()`